# GRUB strange behaviour

Tags: 18.04, server, grub2, kernel

I have Ubuntu 18.04 Server. I find the behaviour of GRUB is strange.

When I uncomment line in /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=on"
```

`intel_iommu` isn't loaded in the kernel.

And when I uncomment line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_iommu=on"
```

`intel_iommu` is loaded in the kernel.

My config:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=on"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_iommu=on"
```

I know that `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` is loaded when is normal mode only. Contrarywise `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` is loaded when is normal mode or recovery mode.

Do it seems my ubuntu load in recovery mode?

Why `intel_iommu` do not load with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`?

Where can I look for a log of GRUB loading?

**EDIT**:

After that, I didn't forget about `sudo update-grub`.

**UPDATE**:

*1. When so*:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=on"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_iommu=on"
```

Result:

```
# sudo virt-host-validate
...
QEMU: Checking if IOMMU is enabled by kernel                               : PASS
...

# dmesg | grep -E "IOMMU"
[    0.000000] DMAR: IOMMU enabled
[    0.000000] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 8 under DRHD base  0xfed91000 IOMMU 1

# cat /etc/modules
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
```

*2. And when so*:

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=on"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_iommu=on"
```

Result:

```
# sudo virt-host-validate
...
QEMU: Checking if IOMMU is enabled by kernel                               : WARN (IOMMU appears to be disabled in kernel. Add intel_iommu=on to kernel cmdline arguments)
...

# dmesg | grep -E "IOMMU"
[    0.000000] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 8 under DRHD base  0xfed91000 IOMMU 1

# cat /etc/modules
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
```

Comment: After any update to grub or initramfs you need to run the appropriate update afterwards or the changes never take affect.

Comment: @Melebius I do 'sudo update-grub' but unfortunately it does not help me. I have no variants.

Comment: @SimpliFixed I do all update but it happens again.

Comment: With it disabled in /etc/grub/default, go look the the correct conf file and see if its enabled there: /boot/grub/grub.conf or /boot/grub2/grub.cfg, look for the kernel line also check dmesg and pipe it into grep and see if DMAR is listed

Comment: What motherboard do you have and what GPU?

Comment: @SimpliFixed When I uncomment the default with intel_iommu, intel_iommu is disappeared from '/boot/grub/grub.conf', DMAR and dmesg show me that intel_iommu don't load. I have ASUSTeK H97M-E, ASUSTeK GTX 950.

Comment: Do you see DMAR in dmesg with it not loaded in grub? Also search dmesg with grep for "IOMMU and also cat /etc/modules

Comment: @SimpliFixed I have updated post.

Comment: Is this a virtual box? How is QEMU being used?

Comment: @SimpliFixed It's problem at the real computer then I use it to run 2 VM. I use KVM. And 2 VM run properly when is uncommented GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX at the real computer. 1 VM use passthrough GPU.